# Writing Hex data to a file

Tags: php

i am trying a piece of code.

```
<?php
$tmp = ord('F'); //gives the decimal value of character F (equals 70)
$tmp = $tmp - 55; //gives 15 - decimal equivalent of 0x0F
$tmp = dechex($tmp); // converts 15 to 0x0F
$fp = fopen("testing.data","wb+");
fwrite($fp,$tmp);
fclose($fp);
?>
```

When i open the file called testing.data in a hex editor, i see 2 bytes written. The 2 bytes are 0x36 and 0x33. 
I am expecting that only 1 byte i.e. 0x0f will be written to the file. This doesn't happen. 
Please help me out with this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Write binary file in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11341506/608639)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to write the byte `0x0f` to the file, simply write the character with that ASCII code. You effectively want to undo `ord`, and the reverse function is [`chr`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.chr.php):

```
<?php
$tmp = ord('F'); //gives the decimal value of character F (equals 70)
$tmp = $tmp - 55; //gives 15 - decimal equivalent of 0x0F
$tmp = chr($tmp); // converts 15 to a character
$fp = fopen("testing.data","wb+");
fwrite($fp,$tmp);
fclose($fp);
?>
```

Comment: +1 `chr` is easier and does the job here. `pack` is more versatile though and allows transforming of multi-byte values with a specified byte order format (little-endian, big-endian, etc.).

Comment: Thanks a lot! :-) i was trying exact opposite.

Answer (score 7):

You are writing the string representation of the number 0x0F to the file (which will use 1 byte per character).

In PHP you would use the [`pack`](http://php.net/pack) function to create binary strings.

```
$bindata = pack('n', 0x0F);
file_put_contents('testing.data', $bindata);
```